# testing field values of an anonymous type in a generic way

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types

I have the following linq to object query:

```
from tb ItemTable
where tb.id =555
select new
{
    field1=tb.field1,
    field2=tb.field2,
    ..
    ..
    ..
    fieldn=tb.fieldn
}
```

Now, it happens that all those field are of the type `string` and I want to tell if any of the field does not contain the substring "ab". But I am wondering if I can avoid having to write a filter such has :

```
where (tb.field1.Contains("ab") == false) && (tb.field2.Contains("ab") == false) ...
```

So my question, is there any way this can be done without using the above?

All the best

Comment: Do you know names `field*`, is it fixed when you writing second `where` code?

Comment: yes, they are known. It is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you cannot iterate the fields of the unknown type, this will require you to iterate the fields using `Reflection` to iterate them:

```
(from tb ItemTable
where tb.id =555
select new
{
    field1=tb.field1,
    field2=tb.field2,
    ..
    ..
    ..
    fieldn=tb.fieldn
})
.Where(item => !item.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    .Any(propertyInfo => ((string)propertyInfo.GetValue(item))
        .Contains("ab"));
```

***Note that reflection is supper slow*** so when doing this kind of stuff repeatedly a lot in your application you should prefer filtering by *code generation*.

Because of the performance of the reflection, and since all the *unknown types* are the same, we can get the properties once instead of getting them every iteration again and again:

```
var tableResults = (from tb ItemTable
    where tb.id =555
    select new
    {
        field1=tb.field1,
        field2=tb.field2,
        ..
        ..
        ..
        fieldn=tb.fieldn
    })

IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos =
    tableResults.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string));

tableResults = tableResults 
.Where(item => !propertyInfos
    .Any(propertyInfo => ((string)propertyInfo.GetValue(item))
        .Contains("ab")));
```

Also, if possible I would try to avoid the *unknown type*, or consider storing the fields in an `Enumerable` if it is appropriate for your application design.

Comment: Great, I was not sure reflecion could have been used on an anonymous type. many thanks

Comment: Note that I have edited the answer, I wrote FieldInfo instead of PropertyInfo by mistake.

Comment: Some efficiency improving: `var infos = results.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties();`

Comment: @ApceHHypocrite Yeah, of course, no reason for getting the properties every iteration, thanks.